# New Note button on related list not working on VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce

Added the following basic tag to a VisualForce page but the New Note button does not function.

VisualForce Page content:

```
<apex:relatedList list="AttachedContentNotes" />
```

Comment: Added fix to this issue in code above to support others.

Comment: You should put the "answer" into the answer. We do encourage self-answered questions. This will let others know that the question has been answered.

Comment: I edited the question with the corresponding answer. Hopefully it provides better insight as to the problem and the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Fixed:

Fix below. You need to hide the chatter feed on the page so the Note object sees it (needs chatter.) You cannot simply set rendered to "false" on the chatter tag (prevents the feed from being detected by the AttachedContentNotes object.) It would be nice if SalesForce updated the Component reference library on related list. See this for more detail on using chatter tags (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm )

Added this to my static resource CSS file:

```
.hidden{ 
  display: none; 
  }
```

Or ifnot using static resource place this on the VisualForce page:

```
<style>
    .hidden{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

VisualForce Page content:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.pdfcssresource_CRE, 'CREresource_CRE.css')}"/>
.....
<!-- AttachedContentNotes uses chatter. Need to embed chatter tag and hide it in order to create Note on VisualForce page --> 
    <div class="hidden">
    <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}" id="ChatterFeed"/>
    </div>
    <!--------------------------------------------------->
    <apex:relatedList list="AttachedContentNotes" />
```